# Liability for workplace accident

Tags: european-union, croatia

Can a person without a degree to sign off engineering projects be liable for damage or accidents caused by them?

If during my employment I, an engineer not qualified in the specific area I'm working in, design a product that doesn't follow all the safety procedures, like a press without two handed controlls or a high platform without any guard rails, can I be liable?

Is there a difference if the employer asked for the unsafe product and insisted even after being warned? What about if they agreed to safety but started using it before safety is installed?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question. A "workplace accident" is when you, as an employee, get hurt.

Comment: But those products are made for use in the workplace and if they're unsafe a workplace accident might occur, be it for me as an employee or any coworker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several related, but not equivalent aspects to consider here:

1. **Liability of the company towards its customers.**
   First off, the company selling the product is bound by several European directives and the corresponding local laws about product safety, namely [2001/95/EG](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richtlinie_2001/95/EG_%C3%BCber_die_allgemeine_Produktsicherheit). The company, as a whole, has to stand in, when a product they produce and sell hurts someone.
2. **Workplace safety**
   Local laws differ, but generally, the company is responsible for the safety of its employees. They have to pay for any injuries an employee suffers. If the company bosses told you to operate a machine that is not safe (or gave you insufficient instructions on how to operate it safely), they may even be criminally liable. This of course implies that the employee has used the machinery to the best of his knowledge. Careless or negligent disabling of security measures or ignoring orders (e.g. to wear a hard hat) will reduce the liability of the company.
3. **Liability of the employee for his work**
   [Here](https://www.haufe.de/arbeitsschutz/arbeitsschutz-office-professional/verantwortung-im-arbeitsschutz-arbeitnehmer_idesk_PI13633_HI2924385.html), it says (for Germany, but I'm quite sure similar rules exist EU-wide):

> Nach § 15 Abs. 1 ArbSchG sind die Beschäftigten verpflichtet, nach ihren Möglichkeiten sowie gemäß der Unterweisung und Weisung des Arbeitgebers für ihre Sicherheit und Gesundheit bei der Arbeit zu sorgen. Gemäß Satz 1 müssen die Beschäftigten auch für die Sicherheit der Personen sorgen, die von ihren Handlungen oder Unterlassungen bei der Arbeit betroffen sind.

> According to [...], the employees are liable to care for their safety and health according to the instructions and order of the employer and according to their capabilities. The employees also have to care for the persons that depend on their acting or non-acting.

You, as an engineer, are expected to be able to judge the (un)safety of the product you design. Not knowing the relevant regulations is not an excuse, as you might look for them or ask someone competent in regulations to provide that for you.

If you are in the bad situation that your management/boss is asking you to hand off a product before you are sure it meets the required standards, I don't really know what the best way forward would be. Probably clearly document that you informed your boss that you have security concerns. And then start searching for a new company...

Comment: I'm a software engineer and this is an issue of mechanical safety, missing fences and stuff like that that are included in my "design", which is just an idea we discussed and assembled piece by piece, so there's no design document. And assembly was stopped before the final safety measures were implemented

It's not handed off to anyone directly, I was testing it and as soon as there were no adjustments needed other than safety I was told not to do any more work on it and show someone how to operate it

Comment: About the second point, ff they tell me to operate something that isn't safe and I comply while fully knowing it isn't safe, who is liable? What if I'm instructed to disable safety measures or someone did it and I know it happened?

Comment: I think this would be up to a court to decide in case something happens. But since you _know_ it's unsafe, you would certainly be hold partially responsible. "I was only executing orders" is not an excuse for breaking a regulation or law, neither in peace nor in war. It may be difficult to stand up against your boss, but I think that's the only option you have to avoid liability.

Comment: @Affaltar I don't know this for a fact, but I *think* anyone with the title of "engineer" is expected to know the limitations of their knowledge and training. I don't know whether you're expected to refuse such design work altogether, or whether you're allowed to do it as long as you the right person takes over and fixes it afterwards. (Certainly you'd be expected to refuse work that could hurt you (like welding the platform together) but nobody ever died directly by drawing pictures on paper.)

Comment: @user253751 That is my assumption, too. But as I read it, the OP is requested to instruct others to use a newly constructed machine, but without the safety measures that were designed for it.

Comment: @user253751 Someone with the title "engineer" is someone who studied engineering or maybe something closely related. A software engineer is a job description for someone with some expertise in computer science, this has absolutely nothing to do with an engineer in the mechanical sense.

Comment: @quarague I know that in many places, "software engineer" means you have a degree in "software engineering". In other places it's unprotected. Such degrees definitely exist - I have one and it is a requirement for being legally employed as a "software engineer" in Germany. (I happen to think that software isn't really engineering, but the authorities think it is)

Comment: @user253751 Software engineer definitely can be a degree but my point was that it gives you no qualifications about classic/ mechanical engineering.

Comment: @quarague I think all engineering degrees are probably expected to teach the general rules of engineering in that country. (Mine is not from Germany)

Comment: @quarague It's not primarily about qualification for a certain engineering domain, it's about common sense. It's expected from an engineer that (s)he has a certain level of general scientific understanding. In this example, it's expected that the software engineer is able to operate and test the machine without the safety measures, because he knows the limitations and when he needs to stop. And he knows that he must not hand of this machine to some "ordinary" worker in that state.